# Save file automatically from IFrame in Node Webkit

Tags: javascript, iframe, node-webkit

I am using node-webkit to automate some common tasks.
I have an iframe which goes to a site address, then clicks save and I have a file save dialog pop out.

Is there any way I can catch the event to save the file witout requiring an external action (like setting the save folder and clicking on save)?

Comment: No.. you can't do that!

Comment: was afraid it's impossible, I thought I'd ask anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to do it that way, but have you thought about just doing an HTTP GET request from node's http module? That's really the beauty of using node-webkit, you get to use node.js!

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var saveLocation = path.join(__dirname, "/cache", "file.txt");

//The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/file.txt'
var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/integers/file.txt'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
    fs.writeFile(saveLocation, str, function (err) {
      if (err) console.log("Problem Saving File.");
    });
  });
}

// Send the request.
http.request(options, callback).end();
```